# Elasticsearch Transportclient fault tolerant retry logic/resiliency

Tags: elasticsearch

I have added 3 trasportclient nodes while creating a client.

```
Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
                    .put("cluster.name", clusterName)
                    .put("client.transport.sniff", true)
               .build();
TransportClient client = new TransportClient(settings);
client.addTransportAddresses(new InetSocketTransportAddress(esHost1, esPort1));
client.addTransportAddresses(new InetSocketTransportAddress(esHost2, esPort2));
client.addTransportAddresses(new InetSocketTransportAddress(esHost3, esPort3));
```

Note that esHost1 and esHost2 are down. But esHost3 is running. However, when I try to connect to the client and execute actions, its giving NoNodeAvailableException. What I was expecting as below as per the Round Robin logic for each actions:

1. try to connect to esHost1
2. NoNodeAvailableException after ping.timeout
3. try to connect to esHost2
4. NoNodeAvailableException after ping.timeout
5. try to connect to esHost3 - and successfully being able to connect.

So now I am beginning to think that the Round Robin is actually for the actions but not in case if there is a NoNodeAvailableException. Is that correct?

Comment: I found: steps 1-5 are actually done in parallel